# Message on bad return value for client side hook script in windows environment

Tags: windows, cmd, tortoisesvn

Today, I stumbled about a very useful feature in `Tortoise SVN`, namely `Client Side Hook Scripts`.

As for me, I want to use a `post_commit` hook in order to rebuild all my projects in trunk automatically. So that I can be sure, that my commit compiles savely in nightly build.

The feature is quite clear and I already have a script that builds all my projects using a windows shell script.

In case, the windows batch script is failing, I wanted to retrieve an email or a message box, that something went wrong.

How, can this be accomplished in the most easiest fashion on a Windows 7 environment?

Comment: What is a window shell script. We don't have such terminology is Windows.

Comment: @CatCat: Thanks for your comments. :-)